# Wildfly 10 UT005024: Could not register resource change listener for caching resource manager

Tags: wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 10 in standalone mode, when I start the Wildfly, I always get the following error messages. The applications deployed. I don't know what caused this error message, and where to look to figure out the root cause. Can anyone help me?

our environment is :

```
java.version = 1.8.0_66
java.vm.info = mixed mode
java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
os.arch = sparcv9
os.name = SunOS
os.version = 5.11
path.separator = :
sun.arch.data.model = 64
```

The following is the stack trace:

```
10:26:32,062 ERROR [io.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) UT005024: Could not register resource change listener for caching resource manager, automatic invalidation of cached resource will not work: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
        at org.xnio.nio.WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.watchPath(WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.java:183)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.PathResourceManager.registerResourceChangeListener(PathResourceManager.java:180)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.ServletResourceManager.registerResourceChangeListener(ServletResourceManager.java:82)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.resource.CachingResourceManager.<init>(CachingResourceManager.java:64)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:579)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:281)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
        at sun.nio.fs.SolarisWatchService$Poller.wakeup(SolarisWatchService.java:261)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.invoke(AbstractPoller.java:222)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.register(AbstractPoller.java:125)
        at sun.nio.fs.SolarisWatchService.register(SolarisWatchService.java:116)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.register(UnixPath.java:897)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.register(AbstractPath.java:104)
        at org.xnio.nio.WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.addWatchedDirectory(WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.java:189)
        at org.xnio.nio.WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.watchPath(WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.java:176)
        ... 10 more
```

Thanks, Helen

Comment: What exact version of JDK? What exact version & arch of solaris?

Comment: I just edited the question with the JDK and solaris version. Please let me know if you need more info.  thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you get any resolution for this?

Comment: Stopped intellij and restarted it and the error disapeared... maybe something similar for you?

Comment: I actually didn't try to fix this issue, and worked on others. now when I check back, the error disappeared.